# cast to to super not working as expected

Tags: java

Why does the second call produces what it does? I thought that by casting `this` to `Super`, only `Super's m1()` should be called!!

```
Super!
And Sub!
---
Super!
And Sub!
```

Code:

```
public class TestSuper {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        (new Sub()).m1();
        System.out.println("---");
        (new Sub()).m2();                // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    }
}

class Super {
    void m1() {
        System.out.println("Super!");
    }
}

class Sub extends Super {
    void m1() {
        super.m1();
        System.out.println("And Sub!");
    }

    void m2() {
        ((Super) this).m1();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why should it? It's the same as Super s = new Sub(); s.m1();

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, casting won't help since it's the *dynamic* type of the object that's used to select the `m1` to call.

The following does the trick:

```
    void m2() {
        super.m1();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question. According to [JLS §15.11.2](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/expressions.doc.html#20860),

> `super.name` is treated exactly as if it had been the expression
>   `((S)this).name`

But this only applies to *fields* of a class, not *methods* (as noted by [@ILMTitan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/143069/ilmtitan)).

Comment: That paragraph of the JLS is only talking about fields. 15.12 talks about methods.